# How to iterate a tree structure with logic on where to stop

Tags: c#, linq

Given a class;

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public string nodeType;
    public string nodeName;
    public List<TreeNode> Children;
}
```

instantiated by ;

```
var tree = new TreeNode()
            {
                nodeName = "Fred",
                Children = new List<TreeNode>()
                {
                    new TreeNode() { nodeName = "James" },
                    new TreeNode()
                    {
                        nodeName = "Lucy",
                        Children = new List<TreeNode>()
                        {
                            new TreeNode() { nodeName = "James",
                                Children = new List<TreeNode>()
                                {
                                    new TreeNode() { nodeName = "Bob" },
                                    new TreeNode() { nodeName = "Kevin" },
                                } },
                            new TreeNode() { nodeName = "Kevin" }
                        }
                    }

                }
             };
```

How would I go about filtering the list by "James" and return the tree as a collection like ;

```
Fred - James
Fred - Lucy - James
```

The smarts is that it does not need to include any child node of the filter criteria. I would like to use  linq if possible but not sure if its possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
IEnumerable<TreeNode[]> Flatten(TreeNode node) =>
    (node.Children ?? new List<TreeNode>())
        .SelectMany(child => Flatten(child))
        .Select(nodes => nodes.StartWith(node).ToArray())
        .StartWith(new[] { node });

IEnumerable<TreeNode[]> results =
    Flatten(tree)
        .Where(nodes => nodes.Last().nodeName == "James");

string text =
    String.Join(
        Environment.NewLine,
        results.Select(nodes =>
            String.Join(
                " - ",
                nodes.Select(node => node.nodeName))));
```

That gives me:

```
Fred - James
Fred - Lucy - James
```

---

Here's a version that doesn't require Microsoft's `System.Interactive` NuGet package:

```
IEnumerable<TreeNode[]> Flatten(TreeNode node) =>
    new[] { new[] { node } }
        .Concat(
            (node.Children ?? new List<TreeNode>())
                .SelectMany(child => Flatten(child))
                .Select(nodes => new[] { node }.Concat(nodes).ToArray()));
```

Comment: Thankyou for your assistance but I have an error "TreeNode[] does not contain a definition of StartWith and no accessible extension method..."

Comment: @gumby - Sorry, I use `System.Interactive` from Microsoft. I'll post a version that doesn't require it.

Comment: Worked a treat and now I have a new library to discover. Many Thanks.